Efficient way to iterate rows in two arrays and then copy array back into a dataframe
I am learning numpy and I have a dataframe of asset prices and thought it might be better to do a calculation in numpy and then put the data back into a dataframe when done.  I have a working program to do this but wonder if there is a more efficient way instead of iterating row by row for cpu and memory if the dataset is large?
I am also wondering if the last move in my code using two dataframes would be more efficient on memory if there were some way to copy the elements of the final array straight into the existing dataframe df1 instead of creating df2, copying it to df1, and then deleting df2?
Here is code that gives the output I am seeking:
But I want it to be efficient with a large dataset.
import pandas as pd
data = [[2,2,2],[2,2.1,2.2],[4,4,4],[6,6,6],[12,12,12]]
columns = ['N1','N2','N3']
index = ['yaba','daba','doo','doo2','doo3']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns, index=index)
print(df1,'\n')

import numpy as np
A = df1.to_numpy()

print('A',A,'\n')

B = np.ones(A.shape,dtype=float)
# iterate down rows to get factors
for i in range(1,A.shape[0]): #
    B[i,:] = A[i,:] / A[i-1,:]
print('B',B,'\n')

# iterate down rows to refactor values
for i in range(1,A.shape[0]):
    B[i,:] = B[i-1,:] * B[i,:]
print('B',B,'\n')

# move B back into df1

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.matrix(B),columns = df1.columns, index = df1.index)
df1 = df2.copy()
print(df1,'\n')
del df2 # free up memory


Output:

      N1    N2    N3
yaba   2   2.0   2.0
daba   2   2.1   2.2
doo    4   4.0   4.0
doo2   6   6.0   6.0
doo3  12  12.0  12.0

A [[ 2.   2.   2. ]
 [ 2.   2.1  2.2]
 [ 4.   4.   4. ]
 [ 6.   6.   6. ]
 [12.  12.  12. ]]

B [[1.         1.         1.        ]
 [1.         1.05       1.1       ]
 [2.         1.9047619  1.81818182]
 [1.5        1.5        1.5       ]
 [2.         2.         2.        ]]

B [[1.   1.   1.  ]
 [1.   1.05 1.1 ]
 [2.   2.   2.  ]
 [3.   3.   3.  ]
 [6.   6.   6.  ]]

       N1    N2   N3
yaba  1.0  1.00  1.0
daba  1.0  1.05  1.1
doo   2.0  2.00  2.0
doo2  3.0  3.00  3.0
doo3  6.0  6.00  6.0  


Please provided runable code when copied: remove > and comment your comments...

"thought it might be better to do a calculation in numpy and then put the data back into a dataframe when done" Why? Pandas has been designed to allow most data processing directly.

Sorry edited once after submitting because it changed everything to run on.   I am going to try to remove >.  This editor is not clear and  it removed my comments but I'll keep trying.

@Julien I thought it would be better to do this in numpy when using large dataset because numpy is supposed to be much faster than arrays and uses less memory.  Is it necessary to down vote my question before even waiting for my response?

I edited my question to add the 4th row which illuminates that some solutions don't continue to provide desired output ;)

Your two `range(1,...) iterations can be replaced two whole-array calculations:
In [140]: B = np.ones((3,3),dtype=float)
     ...: B[1:] = A[1:]/A[:-1]
     ...: B[1:] *= B[:-1]

In [141]: B
Out[141]: 
array([[1.  , 1.  , 1.  ],
       [1.  , 1.05, 1.1 ],
       [2.  , 2.  , 2.  ]])


that's cool.  I'm surprised by -1 in line B[1:] = A[1:]/A[:-1] works this way.  I was under impression -1 referred to the last line in an index but in this case it refers to the row previous to the last row already referenced to the left, i.e. in A[1:]?  thanks

1: is a slice starting with 1, like your range(1,...).  :-1 is a slice up to, but not including the last.

cheers, I get it now.  because : is there it's a slice.

I think the first iteration can be replace by your whole array computation but the second iteration still needed.  otherwise it multiplies the old number one row above instead of the new number. I edited my question to add rows which makes it more apparent.

The thing you are trying to acheive can be done directly in pandas without going to numpy.
You can do it as follows:
import pandas as pd

data = [[2,2,2],[2,2.1,2.2],[4,4,4]]
columns = ['N1','N2','N3']
index = ['yaba','daba','doo']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns, index=index)
print(df1)

B = df1.div(df1.shift(1))
B.iloc[0,:] = 1
print(B)

C = B.shift(1).mul(B)
C.iloc[0,:] = B.iloc[0,:]
print(C)


thanks for reminding me of this, I was aware of this but I am trying to do this in numpy.  The only reason I'm putting back to a dataframe is I have a lot of code already set up to use pandas and I do not want to rework column heading and indices.

is there more pythonic/efficient way in numpy than what I wrote?

@chirob you can refer hpaulj's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78422440/5462372

yes hpaulj's answer is a cool one :)  thanks again

realized if I add another row it is not working, ie the last row should be all 3's.  Should I edit the original question?  I added following: data = [[2,2,2],[2,2.1,2.2],[4,4,4],[6,6,6]]
columns = ['N1','N2','N3']
index = ['yaba','daba','doo','doo2']

From your post, I see that you're trying to improve the performance, so you can try using the polars library: [https://pola.rs/]
I've switched to it from pandas due to better speed. (It really does improve in performance; I'm working with a 6-million rows dataset, and polars outperformed pandas significantly).
Since you mentioned that you'd like to do your calculation in numpy, you can use this function to change your resulting numpy array to a polars DataFrame:
https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.from_numpy.html
But I would highly suggest that you iterate through each row using other functions in polars. I see that you are trying to do some calculations which considers previous index(es)? In that case, you might want to try the rolling functionality in polars:
https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.rolling.html
To combine multiple dataframes, you can either use the concatenate function (to add more rows into your dataframe), or the insert_column function (to add more columns into your dataframe).

Realized I am going about this calculation in the wrong manner. All I need to do whether in pandas or do something similar in np;
print(df1/df1.iloc[0,:])

